# JavaFX - Image Button without button visible (Pics provided)

Tags: java, arrays, image, button, javafx

I have a randomly generated array of colored tiles that I add to a gridpane for a game. As of yet, there is really no functionality, other than the tiles being toggle buttons. Here's a
 [snippet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBLim.png)

I apologize for the obnoxious blue background. I added it just to further clarify my issue.

What you see is my tile images being applied to buttons. What I want is the button borders to (preferably) be nonexistent, or disappear somehow.

*I just want to see my tile images as the buttons themselves.*

I have tried fiddling with borders, clips, opacity, etc... I cannot get anything definitive.

Assuming all necessary imports are there and that the randomlyPopulate method in TileArray is called in another class...

**Tile.java**

```
public class Tile {

/* ----- ATTRIBUTES ----- */

private TileColor color;
private ImageView tileImg = new ImageView();
private ToggleButton tileButton = new ToggleButton(null, new ImageView());

// Constructor used in TileArray
public Tile(TileColor t, ToggleButton b) {

    color = t;
    tileButton = b;
}

// Getter
public ToggleButton getTileButton() {

    return tileButton;
}

// The enumeration used to determine which color tile is being used
// Much easier for debugging to see the color name
enum TileColor {

White,
Black,
Green,
Red
}
```

**TileArray.java**

```
public class TileArray {

/* ----- ATTRIBUTES ----- */

// Initialize the array of tiles
public Tile[][] arrayOfTiles = new Tile[5][5];

private Image whiteTileImg = new Image("image/white_tile.jpg");
private Image blackTileImg = new Image("image/black_tile.jpg");
private Image greenTileImg = new Image("image/green_tile.jpg");
private Image redTileImg = new Image("image/red_tile.jpg");


// Method to randomly populate the array with colored tile objects
// The if statements are intentionally specific, and not 1/4 for each
// Approximates 11 white tiles, 9 black, 3 green and 2 red
public void randomlyPopulate() {

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfTiles.length; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < arrayOfTiles.length; j++) {

            double iRand = Math.random();

            if (iRand <= .44) {

                // Assign an ImageView to the tile and adjust its size
                ImageView view = new ImageView(whiteTileImg);
                view.setFitWidth(90);
                view.setFitHeight(90);

                // Assign a white tile to the array index   
                arrayOfTiles[i][j] = new Tile(TileColor.White, new 
                ToggleButton(null, view));
            }

            if (iRand > .44 && iRand <= .80) {

                // Assign an ImageView to the tile and adjust its size
                ImageView view = new ImageView(blackTileImg);
                view.setFitWidth(90);
                view.setFitHeight(90);

                // Adjust the color of the black tiles
                // Otherwise they are hard to distinguish
                // JavaFX did not take well to my png
                ColorAdjust adjustTileColor = new ColorAdjust();
                adjustTileColor.setBrightness(.14);
                view.setEffect(adjustTileColor);

                // Assign a black tile to the array index   
                arrayOfTiles[i][j] = new Tile(TileColor.Black, new 
                ToggleButton(null, view));
            }

            if (iRand > .80 && iRand <= .92) {

                // Assign an ImageView to the tile and adjust its size
                ImageView view = new ImageView(greenTileImg);
                view.setFitWidth(90);
                view.setFitHeight(90);

                // Adjust the color of the green tiles
                // Otherwise they are hideous
                // JavaFX did not take well to my png
                ColorAdjust adjustTileColor = new ColorAdjust();
                adjustTileColor.setBrightness(-.35);
                adjustTileColor.setSaturation(-.4);
                view.setEffect(adjustTileColor);

                // Assign a green tile to the array index   
                arrayOfTiles[i][j] = new Tile(TileColor.Green, new 
                ToggleButton(null, view));
            }

            if (iRand > .92) {

                // Assign an ImageView to the tile and adjust its size
                ImageView view = new ImageView(redTileImg);
                view.setFitWidth(90);
                view.setFitHeight(90);

                // Assign a red tile to the array index 
                arrayOfTiles[i][j] = new Tile(TileColor.Red, new     
                ToggleButton(null, view));
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Thank you for any assistance, it's greatly appreciated.

-Bagger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call this on your `ToggleButton`:

```
setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
```

Comment: Ah! Padding! I neglected to try this.... Thank you so much. I appreciate the help.